# Get current URL from within a Firefox Addon panel

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

So I've collected 5 different methods to do this, none of which work from within a panel. Firefox is stunningly effective at blocking access to a basic task.

Here's what I've tried:

- Attempt 1:

  ```
  var url = window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href;
  ```

  Error: window.top.getBrowser is not a function
- Attempt 2:

  ```
  var url = window.content.document.location;
  ```

  Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'
- Attempt 3:

  ```
  var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                 .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
                 .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                 .rootTreeItem
                 .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                 .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);
  var url = mainWindow.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href;
  ```

  Error: Permission denied to create wrapper for object of class UnnamedClass
- Attempt 4:

  ```
  var url = window.content.location.href;
  ```

  Error: Permission denied to access property 'href'
- Attempt 5:

  ```
  var currentWindow = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
  var currBrowser = currentWindow.getBrowser();
  var url = currBrowser.currentURI.spec;
  ```

  Error: Permission denied to get property XPCComponents.classes

Coding this for Chrome was a breeze. Not sure why this is so tough for FF.

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser & did u try to `alert` the URL??

Comment: The error messages show that you are running unprivileged code (attempt 3 would normally be the correct approach). Unprivileged code isn't allowed to access browser's user interface, period. If you explain how you are running this code somebody might be able to tell you why it is unprivileged.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use firefox local object:

```
var url = gBrowser.contentDocument.location;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess "Firefox Addon panel" refers to the Addon SDK's [panel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/addon-kit/docs/panel.html) module?

If so you're probably trying to use those snippets in a [content script](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/dev-guide/addon-development/web-content.html). Instead you have to send an event to the main addon's code ([example](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/dev-guide/addon-development/content-scripts/using-port.html)), and in the main addon's code use the [tabs module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/addon-kit/docs/tabs.html):

```
require("tabs").activeTab.url
```

[update] complete testcase, which works for me:

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856282/get-current-url-from-within-a-firefox-addon-panel
exports.main = function() {
  var panel = require("panel").Panel({
    contentURL: "data:text/html,<input type=button value='click me' id='b'>",
    contentScript: "document.getElementById('b').onclick = " +
                   "function() {" +
                   "  self.port.emit('myEvent');" +
                   "}"
  });
  panel.port.on("myEvent", function() {
    console.log(require("tabs").activeTab.url)
  })
  require("widget").Widget({
    id: "my-panel",
    contentURL: "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
    label: "Test Widget",
    panel: panel
  });  
};
```

Comment: Yes, it does refer to the Panel module. But the line you provided causes a slew of errors related to the content-proxy.js file, even if I place it in the main addon's code. Could you show me exactly how you'd use it to get the current url?

Comment: @ChrisKohout: being more specific about "a slew of errors" could help answering you right now; without it I'll have to try my code in add-on builder (later).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the effort. So I added your "self.port.emit('myEvent');" to my content page url (since that contains the textarea that I need to populate with the url), but that generates a "self.port is undefined" error.

Comment: @ChrisKohout: I don't know what's wrong with your code (you didn't redefine 'self', did you?), but you can check the differences with the code I posted (if it works for you) to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Nope, just: <script>self.port.emit('myEvent');</script> It needs to execute automatically (not in a button), so I tried it in the body onLoad as well, no dice.

Comment: @ChrisKohout: sounds like you're still trying to do this from your content page, despite Wladimir's comment. |self| is only defined in content script. See https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/dev-guide/addon-development/content-scripts/access.html for more info.